# Clojure vector as function parameter

Tags: clojure

Being completely inexperienced in clojure, and without any functional programming practice since college, I'm trying to interpret some example code to figure out the clojure syntax.

I started by coding several versions of Fibonacci (https://gist.github.com/pcalcao/ea4176719d778ea3ab9e), but I still can't say I fully understand the more complex forms.

For instance, this:

```
(defn fib_map [n]
  (last (take (+ n 1)
    (map first (iterate (fn [[a b]] [b (+ a b)]) [0 1])))))
```

I'm struggling to really understand the innermost part of this code:

```
fn [[a b]] [b (+ a b)]
```

Now, from my understanding, we're creating an anonymous function that receives one parameter, a vector with two values (this is destructuring, right?), and returns another vector.

Now, what is the reason we would do this, instead of:

```
fn [a b] [b (+ a b)]
```

Are these equivalent? Or are we simply making our anonymous function receive a single parameter as a "gimmick" to use in `iterate`?

Sorry if this is totally obvious, but like I said, Lisp-like languages aren't my strong point yet.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You already figured it out correctly yourself.

Function of the form `(fn [[a b]] ...)` is using destructuring. It takes a single parameter that should be a vector or another type of object that supports clojure's `nth` function. Using destructuring, it "pulls" the first two values out of the vector and assigns them to local variables `a` and `b`.

Function of the form `(fn [a b] ...)` is a function of two parameters. The two are not equivalent.

The reason you have to use the `(fn [[a b]] ...)` form with `iterate` is that `iterate` only works with single-parameter functions.

Comment: Accepted for the more detailed explanation. Also, *first two values of the vector* made me realize that if I pass a coll with more elements the rest will be ignored, I didn't know that! Nice.

Answer (score 2):

It's because iterate only takes two parameters, i.e. one function and one parameter. [cf. the docs](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/iterate)